# Binding one class to another

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constraints

Suppose that I have a class that defines a specific problem, for example, to get the value of some function. But this function can take only specific parameters, i.e. they are biased to some constraints. Here is the simple example:

```
class Problem
{
private:
   std::function<double(const std::vector<double>&)> d_func;
   std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> d_constraints;
public:
   double evaluate(const std::vector<double>& args)
   {
       return d_func(args);
   }
   bool isWithinDomain(const std::vector<double>& args) 
   {
       /*check whether args is in the domain defined with d_constraints*/
   }
};
```

And there is another class Solution that holds a parameter that can be passed to the function defined in `Problem` and the value of that function:

```
class Solution
{
private:
   std::vector<double> d_solution;
   double d_value;
};
```

I can have a lot of possible `Solution`'s but they all have the same boundaries and function to be passed into. So my question is: what is the best way to incorporate `Problem`'s info into `Solution`?  One solution is to have a pointer to `Problem` inside the `Solution`, thus if the constraints or the function are changed in `Problem` we have an updated version of it in every `Solution` instances.
But since c++11 it is deprecated to use raw pointers, so probably I have to go with shared_ptr, but they have performance issues...

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see why it is deprecated to have a normal pointer if that's what you need.. just make sure the Problem instance has a longer lifescope than every Solution

Comment: Raw pointers are not deprecated. It is the fact that using raw pointer for ownership which is *deprecated*.

Comment: @MarcoA. I don't think that using a raw poiner (in my case) is a problem. I said _deprecated_ because I saw a lot of posts on the web about avoiding raw pointers (in general).

Answer (score 3):

1. Raw pointers are **not** (and never will be) deprecated. *Owning* raw pointers are deprecated (or actually discouraged). If you have someone else owning the `Problem` instances, then having a raw pointer to them inside a `Solution` is just fine. You'll have to make sure no `Solution` outlives the `Problem`, of course.
2. If you would like `Solution`s to own the `Problem` objects, however, you should probably turn to shared ownership. You mentioned `std::shared_ptr` has performance issues - what exactly do you mean? Yes, copying or destroying a `shared_ptr` requires atomic operations, but dereferencing does not. Have you done any profiling to be sure it will be an actual problem?

   Never do important design decisions based on a feeling that something will be too inefficient. Always measure first.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Problem` doesn't own the `Solution` object, it is okay to have a normal C pointer in your `Solution` instance pointing to the relative `Problem` it is trying to solve.

Just make sure that your `Problem` object lifescope is longer than your `Solution`s ones.

If one of your `Solution` objects can be shared across multiple `Problem`s (also makes sense) then you might want to use something like a **[factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) class** (pseudocode)

```
class Solution {
    public:
};

class Problem : public Registry /*creation-time registration? Your question doesn't mention that*/ {
    public:
};

// Manages Solution-Problem associations
class Registry {
    public:
        bool /*has the problem been deleted?*/addSolutionToProblem(Solution*,Problem*);
        void deleteSolutionToProblem(Solution*,Problem*);
    protected:
        Registry() {}
    private:
        // Fast N-N range access
        multimap<Problem*,Solution*> psregistry;
        multimap<Solution*,Problem*> spregistry;
};
```

Remember not to violate the [SRP - Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf), that is: if you have to put `new` and `delete` everywhere in your code, perhaps you might want to reconsider your design: one class should have one task (although a complex one).

It's unclear from the question who owns who and what is the nature of the Problem-Solution associations (N-N? 1-N?) and which kind of access you should provide, thus it's hard to give a unique solution here. Pay attention to these details and consider using a `shared_ptr` if you have only one instance of `Problem` that can be shared across a number of proprietary `Solution` objects and needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: In my case it is only one instance of `Problem` that is shared across all `Solution`s. Solution doesn't have to own the `Problem`, it just needs to have an access to the proper `Problem` instance.

Comment: Then the `shared_ptr` way could be the solution. A shared pointer will ensure the `Problem` instance is deleted when all of the `Solution` objects either are destroyed or have their shared pointer out of scope.